# Set value of boolean (type = bit(1)) in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

How can I edit the value of a boolean (type = `bit(1)`) in MySQL Workbench's result grid of a table?

If I set it to `1` or `0` I get the error :

> `ERROR 1406: 1406: Data too long for column 'enabled' at row 1`

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80933, known bug for over a year :/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Write `b'1'` for true, and `b'0'` for false.

Comment: This seems to have limitations. I'm trying it on a new record and it fails. Try it on an already inserted record and it succeeds... MySQL and Workbench 8.0...

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a bug. If you look at the apply script, it converts everything to bit AFTER your first bit cast. Modify the script to remove `b` from everything that's not a bit and new records are created without issue. Something to be conscious of...

Answer (score 7):

To avoid this [well-known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79604), you can also write `01` for true/1 and `00` for false/0.

E.g.

[image]

results in

[image]

which is valid MySql syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `true` `false` keywords for value where `true = 1` and `false = 0`.

MySQL Workbench Version: 6.3.4.0

**UPDATE**

Mysql Server Version: 5.6.27-log

[image]

Comment: I am on 6.3.9, and those keywords are considered as strings, which gives errors when I click on Apply.

Comment: @johanvs 6.3.x has always had this bug, go back to 6.2.5

Comment: Thanks @RichardBenson, but as I have a workaround, I prefer wait for a fix.